# Using jQuery .ScrollTo to switch between Joomla Modules

Tags: jquery, joomla, scrollto

I'm trying to find a way to click a link in one Joomla Custom HTML Module or article and scroll down to another Joomla Module or article.

Is there a way to use the ScrollTo Plugin or another scrolling method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap the Joomla article in a  tag with a certain Id and then ScrollTo that Id?

```
$("#button").click(function() {
     $.scrollTo('.scrollHere');
}


<div id="scrollHere">
Joomla module here
</div>
```

You can find the plugin [here](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Comment: If you can, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @user2316544 - There should be a 'code view' or 'HTML' view in your editor. If you can get to that you can put the JavaScript in a <script> tag at the top of the page and then wrap the Joomla module in the <div> tag with the id corresponding to the $.scrollTo('.scrollHere'); section

Comment: I think this is where it gets tricky. Joomla is very modular , so as far as I know there isn't just one place to put the script because the modules that would have to connect are collected onto a page but aren't on the same page. Hoping that someone reading this has run into similar issues.